# Trying to loop through object with nested object data and use the data in my card to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iteration, lodash

[Example Link](https://codepen.io/1eddy87/pen/MrmZOq/)

I'm trying to loop through an object with nested objects inside so that I can use the values.

The object can be found in my state within the code area below.I need to use the the following so that I can use it in my card as shown below within `render()`

I used `_.mapValues` from lodash and I was able to separate the `color` and `avg` data however, I'm not able to access the `avg` data so that I can use it.

Note: the keys within avg data are always changing so I couldn't use the normal way to access the data:

*for example, `value.avg[key]` this gives me `undefined`*

Please check this [Example Link](https://codepen.io/1eddy87/pen/MrmZOq/) to further understand what I mean and check the console once in the example

DATA I NEED TO USE IN MY CARD TO RENDER

 - color name 'Red'

 - Values from within the avg object

```
    this.state = {
      example: {
        red: {
          avg: {
            "1514505600": 3,
            "1514509200": 20,
            "1514512740": 15,
            "1514516280": 26
          }
        },
        green: {
          avg: {
            "1514505600": 51,
            "1514509200": 315,
            "1514512740": 36,
            "1514516280": 34
          }
        },
        blue: {
          avg: {
            "1514505600": 1,
            "1514509200": 16,
            "1514512740": 14,
            "1514516280": 17
          }
        }
      }
    }

    render() {
      const data = this.state.example;

      _.mapValues(data, function(value, key, object) {
        console.log(value.avg);
        console.log(key);
      });

      const card = (
        <div>
          <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Please check the results in the console for more info</span>

        <div>
          <div>Colour name here: </div>
          <div>Example > avg > value data here: </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )

    return <div>
      {card}
    </div>
  }
```

[Example Link](https://codepen.io/1eddy87/pen/MrmZOq/)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your goal. Are you trying to transform `state` into a specific format, and if so, would you provide an example of that format? Or are you trying to loop over a different portion of the `state`, and if so, would you provide example values you would like to have available in that loop?

Comment: Are you trying to show one card for each color?

Comment: @EricSimonton I'm trying to loop over the example object and get access to the (avg data 24 values  and use the color name) so that I can make a card for each name. This would mean that there would be 10 cards because that's what is currently stored in the state (this number may change)

Comment: @Tom ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: See a working solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do, see example at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/codejockie/pen/mpmgJJ?editors=0011)

I made few changes, see below:
I created `generateCard` method and called it inside the render method.

```
...
generateCard = (data) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(data); // Get array of keys from object

    return keys.map((key, index) => {
      const avgKeys = Object.keys(data[key].avg);

      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <div>Colour name: {key} </div>
          {avgKeys &&
            avgKeys.map(avgKey => {
              return <div key={avgKey}>Example > avg > value data: {avgKey} </div>
            })
          }
      </div>
      )
    })
  }

render() {
    const { example } = this.state;

    const card = (
      <div>
        <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          Please check the results in the console for more info
        </span>

        {this.generateCard(example)}
      </div>
    );

    return <div>{card}</div>;
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Perfect expect I needed the values instead of the keys, no matter I was able to get it working using your codepen example. Thanks for the help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Create a function that generates cards.

```
function generateCard(color, value) {
  return (
    <div key={color+'_'+value}> // arrays need a key to keep them unique
      // your card JSX here
      // use {color} and {value} where necessary
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### 2. Loop through your data.

To access data from an array, you can use `Object.keys(object)` to return an array of keys from an object then use that array to access the data of the object *or* use a library like lodash to simplify the language.

```
var object = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }
var keys = Object.keys(object) // --> ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
keys.forEach(function(key) {
  // key is the key (i.e. 'key1')
  // object[key] is the value (i.e. 'value1')
}

// or, with lodash:

var object = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }
_.forIn(object, function(value, key) {
  // do something with the key and/or value
})
```

Since your data has an object inside an object, you'd need to use this pattern twice. Once data.example and once for value.avg.

#### 3. Tying it together

```
var myCards = [] // array for storing cards

_.forIn(exampleData, function (avgData, color) {
  // do something with the key and/or value
  // avgData is {avg: { ... }}
  // color is the color
  _.forIn(avgData.avg, function (value, key) {
    // do something with the key and/or value
    // store your card from here
    myCards.push(generateCard(color, value))
  })
})

render() {
  <div>
    {myCards}
  </div>
}
```